# $filter not finding result because of data type

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

In JSON i have data like

```
"phaseId":1234
```

and i have written code like

`$filter('filter')(data, {phaseId: phaseId.toString()},true)` this finds results.

but below code does not find. Is there any specific reason for this?

```
$filter('filter')(data, {phaseId: phaseId},true)
```

1234 is of type number and phaseId passed is also number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last parameter `true` (which means strict comparison, will assert that type and value are equals):

```
$filter('filter')(data, {phaseId: phaseId});
```

Comment: But it will find sub strings also rite say i am searching for  1234 then even 12345 also will be given in output right? But i want only exact matches.

Comment: @Hacker I like the first line of code you have.  In JSON, it's easiest to achieve what you are trying to achieve when everything is a String.